# ¿Porque se acumulan sumatorias en un ciclo for que deben presentarse por separado en PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

Poseo una tabla que genera registros con distintos valores, para cada registro habra un valor llamado `atenuante` el cual representa una selección hecha con `checkbox`.

Estos valores son guardados como una `string de la forma`**1-2** y en otro tabla tengo un valor que corresponde a cada opción, siendo algo como:

```
Atenuante: 1 | Valor: 0.2
Atenuante: 2 | Valor: 0.15
Atenuante: 3 | Valor: 0.25
```

En el sistema hago un `explode` para separar el string `atenuante` asi: `1 y 2` y luego buscar su valor en otra tabla. Con el fin de obtener una sumatoria para luego mostrar su valor:

```
1= 0.2 | 2= 0.15 | total = 0.35
```

> Ocurre que me esta calculando bien la sumatoria, pero toma ese total y luego lo suma con el total del siguiente registro, algo así:

```
Registro 1 | total= 0.35
Registro 2 | total= (total real= 0.25) muestra: 0.60
Registro 3 | total= (total real= 0.36) muestra: 0.96
Registro 4 | total= (total real= 0.10) muestra: 1.06
```

Quisiera que cada valor se calculara por separado y así se mostrara, sin irse acumulando:

```
Registro 1 | total= 0.35
Registro 2 | total= 0.25
Registro 3 | total= 0.36
Registro 4 | total= 0.10
```

Este es el código PHP:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT c_atenuante FROM sancionados";
$resultado = mysql_query($query) OR DIE("La consulta $query fallo" . mysql_error());

while ($registros = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) //SI EXISTEN REGISTROS

    {
    $atenuantes = $registros["c_atenuante"];
    echo "<td>" . $atenuantes . "</td>";
    $atenuantes_explode = explode("-", $atenuantes);
    $cantidad_atenuantes = count($atenuantes_explode);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cantidad_atenuantes; $i++)
        {
        $atenuante_seleccionado = $atenuantes_explode[$i] * 1;
        $query3 = "SELECT * from causas_nuevas2 where c_articulo=40 and c_aparte='$atenuante_seleccionado'";
        $resultado3 = mysql_query($query3) OR DIE("La consulta $query3 fallo" . mysql_error());
        if ($registros3 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado3))
            {
            $valor_atenuante = $registros3["valor"];
            $total_circunstancias1 = $total_circunstancias1 + $valor_atenuante;
            }
        }

    echo "<td>" . $total_circunstancias1 . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

?>
```

**NOTA:**

- Verifique el `count`y cada registro muestra la cantidad:     `1 , 2, 2, 1, 2, 1.`.
- Verifique el valor obtenido, y lo hace bien: `1=0.2, 2=0.3: 3=0.15`.
- Multiplico por 1, ya que la tabla donde estan los valores pide un entero, y el explode me genera string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debes de reiniciar tu varaible `$total_circunstancias1 = 0` justo antes de tu `for` recuerda que estas dentro del `While` de todos tus registros entonces cuando cambia de registro mantiene la sumatoria del registro anterior.

Quedaria algo así:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT c_atenuante FROM sancionados";
$resultado = mysql_query($query) OR DIE("La consulta $query fallo" . mysql_error());

while ($registros = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) //SI EXISTEN REGISTROS

    {
    $atenuantes = $registros["c_atenuante"];
    echo "<td>" . $atenuantes . "</td>";
    $atenuantes_explode = explode("-", $atenuantes);
    $cantidad_atenuantes = count($atenuantes_explode);
    $total_circunstancias1 = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cantidad_atenuantes; $i++)
        {
        $atenuante_seleccionado = $atenuantes_explode[$i] * 1;
        $query3 = "SELECT * from causas_nuevas2 where c_articulo=40 and c_aparte='$atenuante_seleccionado'";
        $resultado3 = mysql_query($query3) OR DIE("La consulta $query3 fallo" . mysql_error());
        if ($registros3 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado3))
            {
            $valor_atenuante = $registros3["valor"];
            $total_circunstancias1 = $total_circunstancias1 + $valor_atenuante;
            }
        }

    echo "<td>" . $total_circunstancias1 . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

El error parece tener que ver con la línea:

```
$total_circunstancias1 = $total_circunstancias1 + $valor_atenuante;
```

Pues en esta variable estás acumulando en cada ciclo `while`, y por lo visto quieres que acumule pero sólo dentro del ciclo `for`. Entonces, antes de terminar el ciclo `while` (en tu ejemplo, después del `echo '</tr>;`) debes agregar la línea:

```
unset($total_circunstancias1);
```